# Unity 3D character playing only one animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

I'm trying to make a character "Player" to Idle and then Run when he's moving.

I decided to use an Animator Controller, when I my character have to change his animation, in the Animator Window it does, but nothing is animated. I used 3DS max to export my model / animation into .FBX

Thanks

Comment: When you select you fbx animation in the Project view, you can see some options in the inspector. You should activate "Rig" and Animation Type "Humanoid" if your player is a humanoid. Avatar definition should  be "Create From This Model". Have you done this?